# Haskell attoparsec does not recognize newline while parsing from a text file

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I've been trying to parse a .txt file with some English text in it. My code tries to return back the number of paragraphs in that .txt file. For some reason, attoparsec can't seem recognize a newline or any other characters such as `\n\r\t`. Below is my code. I've also tried using `many1 (satisfy (inClass "\n\r\t"))`, but still no luck. What do you think the underlying problem is? Also here's the [link to the sample text file](https://pastebin.com/Ai10vxPM) I've been testing it on.

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Txt

newtype Prose = Prose {
  word :: [Char]
}

instance Show Prose where
  show a = word a

optional :: Parser a -> Parser ()
optional p = option () (try p *> pure ())

specialChars = ['-', '_', '…', '“', '”', '\"', '\'', '’', '@', '#', '$',
                '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '~', '`', '{', '}',
                '[', ']', '/', ':', ';', ',']

inputPara :: Parser Prose
inputPara = Prose <$> many1' (letter <|> digit <|> space <|> satisfy (inClass specialChars) <|> satisfy (inClass "――.?!") )

paraSeparator :: Parser ()
paraSeparator = many1 (satisfy (isEndOfLine) <|> satisfy (isHorizontalSpace)) >> pure ()

paraParser :: String -> [Prose]
paraParser str = case parseOnly wp (T.pack str) of
    Left err -> error err
    Right x -> x
    where
      wp = optional paraSeparator *> inputPara `sepBy1` paraSeparator

main :: IO()
main = do
  input <- readFile "test.txt"
  let para = paraParser input
  print para
  print $ length para
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `space` parser in the following line:

```
inputPara = Prose <$> many1' (letter <|> digit <|> space <|> satisfy (inClass specialChars) <|> satisfy (inClass "――.?!") )
```

matches characters such as `\n\r\t` (every char which is `isSpace`)

That's why `inputPara` matches the whole text without separation.

One of the solutions could be removing `space` parser from `inputPara` and add `' '` character into `specialChars`

For example, the following code should work, but certainly feel free to choose the option, which works best for you:

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Txt
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

newtype Prose = Prose {
  word :: [Char]
}

instance Show Prose where
  show a = word a

optional :: Parser a -> Parser ()
optional p = option () (try p *> pure ())

specialChars = ['-', '_', '…', '“', '”', '\"', '\'', '’', '@', '#', '$',
                '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '~', '`', '{', '}',
                '[', ']', '/', ':', ';', ',', ' ']

inputPara :: Parser Prose
inputPara = Prose <$> many1' (letter <|> digit <|> satisfy (inClass specialChars) <|> satisfy (inClass "――.?!") )

paraSeparator :: Parser [Char]
paraSeparator = many1 space

paraParser :: String -> [Prose]
paraParser str = case parseOnly wp (T.pack str) of
    Left err -> error err
    Right x -> x
    where
      wp = optional paraSeparator *> inputPara `sepBy1` paraSeparator

main :: IO()
main = do
  input <- readFile "test.txt"
  let para = paraParser input
  print para
  print $ length para
```

Comment: but the above code would separate the text by words. I want the text to be separated by paras. The output for the pastebin link I attached should return a length of 3.